# How to create a key-value array from a text file in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, file

I am trying to create a dictionary for a multi-lingual web site. I have a textfile which contains some data in `KEY = "VALUE"` format.

```
STACKOVERFLOW="Stackoverflow"
ASKING_A_QUESTION="Asking a Question"
...
```

I want to get the words on the left hand side of the `=` character as keys and the words on the right as corresponding values.

My result should be like

```
echo $resultArray['STACKOVERFLOW']; // Stackoverflow
```

Comment: Loop through your text file, split (explode) each line ("="), add the result to your associative array ($arr[$key] = $value).

Comment: You should be able to work this out yourself with very basic research of PHP functions: Read file line by line (http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php), split strings (http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

Comment: Key-value-pairs are a bad idea for internationalization. Instead, have a look at gettext, or check what frameworks like Symfony do. You will thank yourself in a few months.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [parse_ini_file()](http://php.net/manual/it/function.parse-ini-file.php):

```
; file:
[second_section]
path = "/usr/local/bin"
URL = "http://www.example.com/~username"
```

Code

```
// Parse without sections
$ini_array = parse_ini_file("sample.ini");
print_r($ini_array);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [path] => /usr/local/bin
    [URL] => http://www.example.com/~username
)
```

Comment: Awesome. Exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php

Answer (score -2):

See my comments. (Code is not tested)

```
//Get the content of your file into an array by rows
$content = file('yourfile.txt');
//Init an array
$array = array();
//Set the number of current row
$i = 1;
//Looping on each rows
foreach ($content as $row) {
    //Explode the row by = sign
    $tmp = explode("=", $row);
    //If we have exactly 2 pieces
    if (count($tmp) === 2) {
        //Trim the white space of key
        $key = trim($array[0]);
        //Trim the white spaces of value
        $value = trim($array[1]);
        //Add the value to the given key! Warning. If you have more then one
        //value with the same key, it will be overwritten. You can set 
        //a condition here with an array_key_exists($key, $array);
        $array[$key] = $value;
    } else {
        //If there are no or more then one equaltion sign in the row
        die('Not found equalation sign or there are more than one sign in row: ' . $i);
    }
    //Incrase the line number
    $i++;
}
//Your result
var_dump($array);
```

Comment: I do not really understand without any comment, why i was devoted.